# Как имитировать ЗАЖАТИЕ кнопки на клавиатуре вне формы

Tags: c#

В одном из методов требуется зажатие определённой клавиши, пока верно условие. Я использую голосовое управление в программе. Когда я пытался сделать нажатие клавиши в бесконечном цикле (бесконечном, т.к. клавиша зажата всё время пока условие верно) так

```
static void keyBDPress()
        {
            for ( int F = f; F == 1;)
            {
                SendKeys.Send("W");
            }
        }
```

то у меня возникла проблема, я не могу изменить условие (программа выполняет цикл, а не функцию отвечающую за распознавание речи). Эту проблему я не хочу решать через многопоточность. Я решил просто использовать зажатие клавиши. Вот код

```
static void keyBDPress()
        {
            if (f == 1)
            {
                //SendKeys.Send("W");
            }
        }
```

Вместо SendKeys.Send("W") нужно использовать ЗАЖАТИЕ клавиши. Пожалуйста помогите!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void KeyboardAction(Key key, Keyboard.KeyDownEvent routedEvent)
    var target = Keyboard.FocusedElement;    // Target element

    target.RaiseEvent(
        new KeyEventArgs(
            Keyboard.PrimaryDevice,
            PresentationSource.FromVisual(target),
            0,
            key)
        { RoutedEvent = routedEvent }
    );
}
```

и использование:

```
KeyboardAction(Key.W, Keyboard.KeyDownEvent); // нажатие
KeyboardAction(Key.W, Keyboard.KeyUpEvent); // отжатие
```

база для ответа взята из: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1646568/4423545

нагуглил по запросу "c# keydown sendkeys"

Comment: Это нажатие, а не зажатие =) Зажатие нужно будет отлавливать флажок, и если кнопку отпустим убираем флажок.

Comment: Отколе `KeyDownEvent` это нажатие? Нажатие это `KeyDownEvent` с последующим `KeyUpEvent`. Я же, даже, в комментарии так и написал: `ивент нажатия клавиши (без отжатия)`. А про флажки не понял.

Comment: А видать не туда посмотрел. Ну а как это будет при отпускании себя вести?

Comment: Ну нужно писать аналогичный код на `KeyUpEvent` и пробовать. Пробуй. На сам изначальный вопрос я ответил.

Comment: Логично, но ТС может не знать об этом и будут траблы. А так, предупрежден, вооружен!